# Parsing data using Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse out job information from HTML page using Jsoup parser. I am trying to extract all the job posting details, however I just couldn't get the query right. I tried into Tryjsoup.com to get idea of query structure but I can't figure out how can I get these tuples and also please inform on how to get a grip on their inner structure

Html Code:

```
 <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting" type="tuple" id="131015000050" class="row  ">
<a count=1 href="some link">
<span itemprop=title><font class=hlite>Developer</font></span>
<span itemprop=hiringOrganization>Vm World</span>
</a>
</div>
<div class= "other details"><span itemprop=baseSalary><em></em>3000</span></div>
```

Expected Output:

String Post = Developer

String Company = Vm World

String Salary = 3000

Comment: Please add to your question what exactly you expect to get from the HTML. Any example output would be good for that.

Comment: @luksch I have added the expected output. Still my question remains how to get the div tuple

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to use `Element.select("span")` for the block of HTML code.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<HTML code>");
Elements spans = doc.select("span");
for(Element span: spans) {
    System.out.println(span.text());
}
```

The result of the above code:

```
Developer
Vm World
3000
```

---

Code for segregatiton:

```
Element title = doc.select("span[itemprop=title]").first();
Element post = doc.select("span[itemprop=hiringOrganization]").first();
Element salary = doc.select("span[itemprop=baseSalary]").first();
System.out.println(title.text());
System.out.println(post.text());
System.out.println(salary.text());
```

Comment: Your query does work but however it doesnt find the salary in div[other_class] . Also I cannot segregate the data based on title, post and salary.

Comment: Jsoup cannot identify 'itemprop' in span so getting a blank output.